# Set focus to a textbox in a nested iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use TinyMce in my app. So, I have nested body elements and iframes. One from my html page, and one from the TinyMce. To the body of the tinymce I append div with many textboxes. Their ids are hello1, hello2 etc.

How to set focus to 'hello1'?

This code:

```
$iframe.contents().find('body').find('hello1')
```

returns the correct textbox.

But this:

```
$iframe.contents().find('body').find('hello1').focus()
```

doesn't work. How to solve this?

Comment: Try `click()` instead of `focus()`

Comment: what is `comment0`? a class or an id? how that returns the correct textbox?

Comment: @Raminson hello1 is the id of the textbox. When I execute $iframe.contents().find('body').find('hello1') in Chrome, in the console I get the correct object.

Comment: if `hello1` is an id you should use `$iframe.contents().find('body').find('#hello1').focus()`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

`$iframe.contents().find('body').find('hello1').focus()` -> `$iframe.contents().find('#hello1').focus()`

It looks to me like you are just missing the `#` in your ID selector. Also lonesomeday is right, `.find('body')` is un-needed, as `.contents()` already contains your element.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to focus both the element and the relevant `iframe`.  Each frame is a different window, effectively, so each can have a focused element. So only the focussed element in the focussed `iframe` will be actually selected.

```
$iframe.focus().contents().find('#hello1').focus()
```

Again, as others have said, you also need `#hello1`, rather than just `hello1`, to select the element by its `id`. Note also that you can remove `.find('body')`, since presumably there is only one element by that `id` in the document.

Comment: Shouldn't the event bubble to the iFrame element?

Comment: @Fresheyeball No, since it's in a different document.

Comment: Interesting. So you could actually end up with `focus` being out of sync? As in an element in the iFrame has focus, but the user is not using it, but using another element that also has focus outside the iFrame?